# Jquery Sortable, items inside li are able to be dragged and dropped

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery sortable.

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li class="image-item gallery-image-item"><i class="btn-comment icon-comment icon-2x"></i><i class="btn-youtube icon-youtube-play icon-2x"></i><i class="btn-delete icon-remove"></i></li>
    //...more similar li's
</ul>
```

The problem is, I can drag and drop each li, but the icons situated inside each li are able to be dragged and dropped as well, separately to it's parent li. Is there a way to stop this?

JS:

```
$("#gallery").sortable({items: ':not(:last-child)'});
```

Comment: share your jquery code for drag and drop

Comment: $("#gallery").sortable({items: ':not(:last-child)'});

Comment: try providing different class to image and include that in items tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X3rKJ/ see this and you can exclude the item from being drag and  dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide a `handler` property:

```
handle: 'li'
```

Which will bind the event to the actual `li` themselves.

Comment: This stops everything from being draggable.